# Android: Create An Intent IF a condition is met?

Tags: android, android-intent

Evening

Currently my system allows the user to enter their username and password, if these are entered correctly, their role will be selected from the database and displayed in a textview.

However I'm also attempting to allow the user to move to the menu page if their login details are correct. My issue is that the user is being redirected to the main page when they click the login button regardless of whether their details are correct. I attempted to surround the intent with an if clause however that had no affect.

```
    public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private TextView roleField;
    private Context context;


    public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView roleField) {
        this.context = context;
        this.roleField = roleField;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try{
                String username = (String)arg0[0];
                String password = (String)arg0[1];

                String link = "*";
                String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                wr.write( data );
                wr.flush();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }
                return sb.toString();

            }
            catch(IOException e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.roleField.setText(result);

    }
   }
```

With the login calls the sign in constructor in the mainactvity page

```
public void loginPost(View view){

        String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
        new SigninActivity(this,role).execute(username,password);


        if(role!= null){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Whats the `if` condition / line? Clearly that Activity is always being started / invoked.

Comment: `if(role != null){}` My idea was the if they were in the database they would have a role, and if not role would be equal to 'zero'

Comment: decide what to on  onPostExecute(), depending upon correclty logined or not

Comment: @farhanlatheef I attempted to add the code to the postexecute method however, it gave me an error stating it cannot resolve constructor

Answer (score 3):

> I attempted to surround the intent with an if clause however that had no affect.

Your logics to doing this (I mean logging  a user in) is not correct. You should revise your codes.

First of all, `AsyncTask`s are not of type `Activity`. So, name `SigninActivity` is a bit misleading. Please rename it for experiencing better feelings about Android SDK programming.

The basic steps for implementing a typical login Activity is listed as follows. Please follow the steps.

- Create a `LoginActivity` class and register it to `AndroidManifest.xml` as the default entry point to your app whenever users click on it in launcher.
- In its `onCreate` check whether the user is already signed in or not.
- If she is, redirect her to your main activity via:

  ```
   startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
  ```
- If she is not, She should fill credentials fields you have presented for her by UI of your login activity.
- Once she pressed <kbd>Login</kbd> button, show a so-called "Please Wait..." message for her to feeling better UX. Meanwhile you are starting `LoginAsyncTask`.
- In its `doInBackground` contact your server or wherever you want for authenticating her. And return the result.
- In its `onPostExecute`, first hide that "Please Wait..." message and then inform her of hers authentication.
- If she was successfully authenticated, redirect her to your main activity.

Comment: Thank you @abforce for your in depth response. Do you have any particular website or tutorial series that would have more information on developing this type of login chain?

Comment: As [I've googled this topic](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=android+implement+login+screen+asynctask), seems there are a bunch of examples and tutorials. Have a look there.

Comment: Actually Im reading through your suggestion isn't my code doing what you're suggesting?

Comment: @CodingKids Your `AsyncTask` seems good but your `LoginActivity` needs some revision.