# How to get a login activity before mainactivity

Tags: android

is it possible to get a login activity in between splash and main activity in android studio.`it should be after splash activity and before main.how to get it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Register"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Just set the first Activity to your LoginActivity.

Comment: then what is problem?

Comment: I want splash activity as first and then login,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your manifest like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/icon"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginPage"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainPage"></activity>
</application>
```

and make sure your intents are appropriare in order

Answer (score 1):

When you call splash activity, inside splash activity just call loginactivity and if you are on login activity, on press of the button, call mainactivity. That's it.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private final int STR_SPLASH_TIME = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        startSplashTimer();
    }

    private void startSplashTimer() {
        try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, STR_SPLASH_TIME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

From **SplashActivity**, it will be going to the **LoginActivity**, when this happened after that onclick of the button call **MainActivity**.

So your flow should be like this,

> SplashActivity --> LoginActivity --> MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question two or three weeks ago. Find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801002/1841194).

However, in my opinion, creating an activity just for showing a splash is not so good. Essentially, your app should have as few activities as it can. Activities are, with no doubts, the main and heaviest component for an app. So, for just showing a splash for you may want to show that splash in your `LoginActivity` until further resources are loaded. Once all are loaded, you can hide that splash and show log-in form.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_activity);

            ...
            if(!alreadyLoggedIn()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_activity);

            if(loginSuccessful()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // show ERROR
            }
    }
}
```